# writing to /dev/ttyO3 not visible

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, uart

I am writing the data to `/dev/ttyO3` in my application .The write is succeeded but not visible int he `cat /dev/ttyO3.`
ttyO3 is the device name for the uart4 instance of omap4460 pandaboard.

Edit 1:But some pulses are showing up when I probe through CRO.
How should I change my code to enable the software loop back?ie(I want the same pulse to be seen at rx pin without shorting Tx-Rx)

```
#define DEVICE "/dev/ttyO3"

int main()
{
    int fd;
    int write_fd1;
    struct termios options;
    fd = open(DEVICE,O_RDWR);

    if(fd < 0)
        printf("unable to open the device\n");
    else
        printf("device opened %d \n",fd);
    tcgetattr(fd,&options); 
    cfsetospeed(&options,B300);
    cfsetispeed(&options,B300);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&options); 
    tcgetattr(fd,&options); 

    if((cfgetospeed(&options) != B300) || (cfgetispeed(&options)!= B300));
    {
        printf("Baud rate not set");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        write_fd1 = write(fd,"a",2) ;
        printf("write_fd %d \n",write_fd1);
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting some code? It is rather impossible to guess the way you wrote your code. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `/dev/tty03`, with a zero, not a capital oh. Is it written that way in your code?

Comment: @UncleO -- *"It should be `/dev/tty03`"* -- The device name with capital 'O' is correct. That's the convention for serial ports of kernels on OMAP devices, instead of "ttyS3".  And if the device name had been misspelled, then the **open()** call would have failed.

Comment: Proper coding dictates that you should be testing the return codes from all syscalls, including **tcgetattr()** and **tcsetattr()**.  Your code for "testing" the baud-rate setting is broken, and can produce a meaningless "valid" result.